# Finding a pattern in a PHP file and reading the number after that pattern

Tags: php, regex, string

I Am working on a project that requires me to find all of the functions across several hundreds of php files, and return the line number that the function was first created on, as well as the line number that the function closes on. The entire file is loaded in as a string, and each line within the file begins with a line number. I have found the number that the functions start on, and have in variables the function name, meaning that i can establish a pattern, but cant seem to narrow down a way to figure out where it ends.

A portion of the string may look something like this:

```
Line11 blah blah blah Line12 function doSomething ( $foo, $fab ) Line13 { Line14 ... Line15 { Line16 ... Line18 ... Line19 ... Line21 if (... ) Line22 ... ( ... ); Line23 break; Line24 } Line25 die ( ... ); Line26 } Line27 Blah Blah Blah
```

In this case, I would need to know that the function ends on line 26.

Ive tried using a function to get the number by matching reliable patterns on each side of it:

function for finding strings between patterns:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}


$name = 'doSomething';
$paradigm = '$foo, $fab';
$start = 12;
$mess = 'Line'.$start.'function'.$name.'('.$paradigm.')'.'/\{([^{}]|(?R))*\}/'.' Line';
$lineNum = get_string_between($string, $mess, ' ');
echo $lineNum;
```

I was expecting an output of `26`, but currently, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Hmmm... https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getstartline.php https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getendline.php not much doc for them though.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work for me anyway, since that (appears to) require me to need to run it in the file i'm scanning. However, I don't have the ability to edit those.

Comment: If you can find the start of the function, then create a LIFO stack of `{` characters, removing from the stack when you hit a `}` character. When the stack length is zero, then you have the end of the function. Not very efficient, but should be reliable and not dependent on formatting of code, etc.